# SQL Linked Tables, INSERT INTO & JOINs

Tags: sql, join, linked-server, insert-into

I am new so please be gentle.

Been using SQL server 2008r2 to create a working database based on information pulled from a larger, proprietary SQL database on another server.  I am able to pull info into the new table using an INSERT INTO function, but when I attempt to add a linked field from another table on the linked database via a join, I get nowhere.  Without further ado, here is my query in all its newbish glory:

```
INSERT INTO [Cust_Info].[dbo].[form_data]
        (CustNo
        ,LastName
        ,FirstName
        ,Add1
        ,Add2
        ,City
        ,State
        ,Zip
        ,Phone1
        ,Phone2
        ,Email)
SELECT      [CustNo]
        ,[LastName]
        ,[FirstName]
        ,[Add1]
        ,[Add2]
        ,[City]
        ,[State]
        ,[Zip]
        ,[Phone1]
        ,[Phone2]
        ,[Email]

FROM [XYZ-SERVER-1\ETC].[Service].[dbo].[Customer]
JOIN [XYZ-SERVER-1\ETC].[Service].[dbo].[EmailInv] 
ON [Cust_Info].[dbo].[form_data].[CustNo]=[XYZ-SERVER-1\ETC].[Service].[dbo].
[EmailInv].[CustNo]
```

I am sure I am making a very noob mistake, but I continue to get "Msg 4104"s on the "ON" line, and a "Msg 209" (Ambiguous column name 'CustNo') on the first line of the select statement.

I have sorted through many related posts on different forums, and by my account this should work.  Can one of you vets please show this noob the light?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one thing I notice is you are attempting to `INSERT INTO` your table `[Cust_Info].[dbo].[form_data]` but you are not `JOINing` on this table in the `JOIN` statement.  So your JOIN syntax does not appear to be correct.  I am guessing you are trying to `JOIN` this way, please notice that I used aliases:

```
INSERT INTO [Cust_Info].[dbo].[form_data]
(
    CustNo
    ,LastName
    ,FirstName
    ,Add1
    ,Add2
    ,City
    ,State
    ,Zip
    ,Phone1
    ,Phone2
    ,Email
)
SELECT [CustNo] -- which table is this from select the alias? 
    ,[LastName]
    ,[FirstName]
    ,[Add1]
    ,[Add2]
    ,[City]
    ,[State]
    ,[Zip]
    ,[Phone1]
    ,[Phone2]
    ,[Email]

FROM [XYZ-SERVER-1\ETC].[Service].[dbo].[Customer] c
JOIN [XYZ-SERVER-1\ETC].[Service].[dbo].[EmailInv] e
    ON c.[CustNo]=e.[CustNo]
```

but you also need to specify which table, each of the columns is coming from. For example, the `[CustNo]` in the `SELECT` is in two tables, which one do you need?

Comment: This did the trick.  Assigned ALIAS to Customer and EmailInv tables and preceded all fields in SELECT statement C or E respectively. My final lines are: FROM [XYZ-SERVER-1\ETC].[Service].[dbo].[Customer]AS C
INNER JOIN [XYZ-SERVER-1\ESC].[Service].[dbo].[EmailInv] AS E
ON C.[CustNo]=E.[CustNo]  Now it is just a matter of getting the data to cooperate. :)  Thanks again!

Comment: @HLGEM thanks for the edit, obviously I did not fully reread this before posting. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `CustNo` is a field in both tables, so SQL doesn't know which one to choose.

try:

```
INSERT INTO [Cust_Info].[dbo].[form_data]
        (CustNo
        ,LastName
        ,FirstName
        ,Add1
        ,Add2
        ,City
        ,State
        ,Zip
        ,Phone1
        ,Phone2
        ,Email)
SELECT      [Customer].[CustNo]
        ,[LastName]
        ,[FirstName]
        ,[Add1]
        ,[Add2]
        ,[City]
        ,[State]
        ,[Zip]
        ,[Phone1]
        ,[Phone2]
        ,[Email]

FROM [XYZ-SERVER-1\ETC].[Service].[dbo].[Customer] 
JOIN [XYZ-SERVER-1\ETC].[Service].[dbo].[EmailInv] 
ON [Cust_Info].[dbo].[form_data].[CustNo]=[XYZ-SERVER-1\ETC].[Service].[dbo].
[EmailInv].[CustNo]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  This is close to what needed!  Much thanks!

Comment: I would like to know why I receive a downvote. Downvoter, please leave a comment

Comment: @duke_of_dork why this answer was "close" and not correct for you ? It's a Join, so CustNo field will be the same in both tables. It's indistint which one you choose

Comment: ElV- i did not downvote.  i needed that information as well, but bluefeet hit the nail on the head.  i did need to distinguish between the tables, but the ALIAS concept is what made my query work. Thus, why you were close but I didn't choose you as my answer.  I still REALLY appreciate your input. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have custno in both tables.  You should precede it with Customer.CustNo to identify the source table:

```
select Customer.CustNo, . . .
```

Apparently, no other columns are duplicated between the tables.  In general, when doing joins, it is a good idea to precede all referenced columns (anywhere) with their source tables.